# Difference between run time and compile time initialization of array of structures

Tags: c, structure

I somewhere read "You cannot initialize a structure like this at run time."
example:

```
#define NOOFITEM 12


    struct item_info
    {
          char itemname[15];
          int quantity;
          float retail;
          float wholesale;
     }item[NOOFITEM];
    int main()
    {
           item[0]={"rice",10,40,30};
           item[1]={"sugar",10,40,30};
           item[2]={"soap",10,40,30};
    }
```

But if you want to assign values at run time then you have to do it manually like:

```
int main()
{
      strcpy(item[0].itemname, "rice");
        item[0].quantity = 10;
        item[0].retail = 40;
        item[0].wholesale = 30;
}
```

I tried in internet but am unable to know the differences. I want to know the difference between those two in terms of run time and compile time.
Please explain me also the below one. Is this run time or compile time? How does we actually decide which is run time and which is compile time!

```
struct item_info
{
      char itemname[15];
      int quantity;
      float retail;
      float wholesale;
}item[NOOFITEM] =
{
    {"rice",10,40,30},
    {"sugar",10,40,30},
    {"soap",10,40,30}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn’t really related to the difference between compile time and run-time, but to the difference between initialization and assignment. An initialization is always part of a declaration.

For example

```
int a = 5; // declaration with initialization
int b; b = 5; // declaration (without initialization) followed by an assignment
```

The syntax you try to use (in your first example) to assign to a structure can only be used for initialization, that is, in the declaration itself. In your last code snippet, you initialize during declaration, which is fine.

As a way to get around this syntactical restriction, you can use compound literals (added in C99), a parenthesized type name followed by a list of initializers enclosed by `{` … `}`:

```
struct item_info
{
    char itemname[15];
    int quantity;
    float retail;
    float wholesale;
} item[NOOFITEM];

int main(void)
{
    item[0] = (struct item_info){ "rice", 10, 40, 30 };
    item[1] = (struct item_info){ "sugar", 10, 40, 30 };
    item[2] = (struct item_info){ "soap", 10, 40, 30 };
}
```